# How to get server's time and port it into this JavaScript function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery script but instead of getting the time from my computer, how can I get the time on page arrival using the server's time using PHP? No counting or changing in time is needed.

```
$(function () {
  var now = new Date();

$('#date').scroller({
    preset: 'datetime',
    minDate: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()),
    theme: 'android-ics',
    display: 'inline',
    mode: 'scroller',
    dateOrder: 'ddM',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'HH:ii:ss',
    timeWheels: 'HHii',
    stepMinute: 10,
    rows: 3

   }).scroller('setDate', now, true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dynamically insert the time value from PHP into the output javascript.

```
var serverTime = <?php echo time(); ?>
```

Obviously you can format the time however you want, this example just unix timestamp.

Then use in you jQuery like this:

```
             $('#date').scroller({
                preset: 'datetime',
                minDate: serverTime,
                theme: 'android-ics',
                display: 'inline',
                mode: 'scroller',
                dateOrder: 'ddM',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                timeFormat: 'HH:ii:ss',
                timeWheels: 'HHii',
                stepMinute: 10,
                rows: 3

            }).scroller('setDate', now, true);
```

Comment: Not quite correct, JavaScript timestamps are in milliseconds. Something like this would be better: `var serverTime = <?php echo round(microtime(true)*1000); ?>;`

Comment: @Kolink Yes. I mentioned that it would need to be formatted as necessary, I don't think he was looking for timestamp format anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used this one and it seems to work `var now = new Date(<?php echo date("Y, m, j, G, i, s");?>);` with one problem. Instead of showing 06 for the month, it shows 07. I used outside of the JS this to check it `<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>` and it gives me 06 for the month. How come?!

Comment: @Kaoukkos Try `date("Y, m-1, j, G, i, s")` for your date format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the jQuery is inline in your PHP page, you can replace the `new Date(...` with `<?php  echo date(Y:m:d); ?>`

You could also insert a function for an ajax request to get the time from your server.